# Swift keep array order whilst filling it

Tags: arrays, swift

So, I have a 2D array called `allBusinesses` of type `BusinessClass`. I fill this array in the following way:

```
allBusinesses[0].append(contentsOf: [B11, B12, B13, B14, B15, B16])
allBusinesses[1].append(contentsOf: [B21, B22, B23, B24, B25, B26])
```

Where `B11`, `B12` ... `B26` are all `BusinessClass` instances.

I have another 2D `BusinessClass` array called `myOwnedBusinesses`. I create it the following way:

```
var myOwnedBusinesses: [[BusinessClass]] = [[], []]
```

In my application, I have a `tableView` which contains all elements of `allBusinesses`, where each section contains the rows of the second dimension of the array, so that: `allBusinesses[section][row]`. When I select a random cell in the `tableView`, the corresponding `BusinessClass` element is added to the `myOwnedBusinesses` array, in the following way:

```
myOwnedBusinesses[selectedSection].append(allBusinesses[selectedSection][selectedRow])
```

As you can imagine from seeing the code, if I for instance select the cell at section 0 row 3, then select the cell at section 0 row 2, the order of `myOwnedBusinesses` will be wrong, being the opposite of what `allBusinesses` is. As a conclusion, I want to maintain the same order between the two arrays, even though the `myOwnedBusinesses` array is not always filled.

Comment: What is the algorithm for knowing what the "right" order of `myOwnedBusiness` would be? Even more: Do you really need this array? Why not just keep a list of selected index paths? After all, that list would tell you what your owned businesses are, just by indexing into `allBusinesses`. It seems silly to duplicate the info when you already have the info.

Comment: Let's say that in section 0 of myOwnedBusinesses I first add B14 and than B11. The array displays first B14, being added first. Nevertheless this is wrong, for I want the order of myOwnedBusinesses to be the same of allBusinesses array.

Comment: @matt It may look useless but this is because I did not explain the application in detail. Only some of the businesses (the ones which are selected) have to pursue some functions, and without this second array I would have to do a futile selection in the original array. Creating 2 is much simper and more memory efficient.

Comment: But let's say B14 is in the array. There is nothing about it that tells you what its index path was; it is unmarked, as it were. So there is nothing about B11 that tells you what order they should go in. It is just a bare BusinessClass object. But if you use index paths, they have a natural sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
let section0 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
let section1 = ["h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m"]
section0.index(of: "b")
var all:[[String]] = [[],[]]
all[0].append(contentsOf: section0)
all[1].append(contentsOf: section1)
```

To keep the original indexes flatten the original array

```
let all_flat = all.flatMap {$0}
```

Let's say the user selects the cells in this order : "d", "e", "a", "h", "m", and "k".

```
var myArray = [["d", "e", "a"], ["h", "m", "k"]]
```

And then sort each array inside `myArray`

```
myArray = myArray.map {
    $0.sorted { str1, str2 in
        return all_flat.index(of: str1)! < all_flat.index(of: str2)!
    }
}
```

For your case :

```
let allBusinesses_flat = allBusinesses.flatMap {$0}
myOwnedBusinesses = myOwnedBusinesses.map {
    $0.sorted { b1, b2 in
        return all_flat.index(of: b1)! < all_flat.index(of: b2)!
    }
}
```

This solution is expensive, memory wise. Storing the selected indexes would be preferable.